# Request Matcher not working to permit allowed path

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am following an older tutorial to implement Spring Security. Unfortunately, `antMatchers` is not recogzied as a method in my configuration class, so after doing some research, I believe `requestMatchers` method is its equivalent. However, the path (`/`) remains blocked without authentication. I would like to permit this.

Here is my controller:

```java
package com.quadri.springsecurity.controllers;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.quadri.springsecurity.models.Student;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/students")
public class StudentController {

    private static final List<Student> STUDENTS = Arrays.asList(
        new Student(1, "James Bond"),
        new Student(2, "Maria Jones"),
        new Student(3, "Anna Smith")
    );

    @GetMapping(path = "{studentId}")
    public Student getStudent(@PathVariable("studentId") Integer studentId) {
        return STUDENTS.stream()
        .filter(student -> studentId.equals(student.getStudentId()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Student " + studentId + " does not exist!"));
    }
}
```

Here is my config file:

```java
package com.quadri.springsecurity.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers( "resources/**", "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

In my resources/static folder I have created a simple html page (`index.html`) displaying hello world. In the tutorial the `RequestMapping` wasn't changed, however they used `.antMatcher` in the config file which is not a recognized method in Spring Security at least the version I am using. Here is my POM for reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.quadri</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What is the proper way to make sure the home or "/" URL is permitted?

Comment: `SecurityWebFilterChain` is used for reactive applications. Let your `@Configuration` class extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and override the `void configure(HttpSecurity)` method.

Comment: The WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter methods are deprecated https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should allow `index.html` in the `HttpSecurity` request matchers as going to `/` is doing an auto-redirect to `index.html` and there is no permit rule defined for `index.html` giving an auth prompt. Below setting should work:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers( "/resources/**", "/", "/index.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();

    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, issues can come out from the Spring Boot newest
version you use, which as it is in the pom is 3.0.1. As you can see
[here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes),versions 3.0 and afterward, are based on the Spring framework 6.0. The Spring framework 6.0 also uses the [Spring Security 6.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/releases/tag/6.0.0),,
where, antMatchers() (as well as other Matcher methods) are deprecated
for Spring security configurations. [See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/whats-new.html) and [here]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11939).

Moreover, I suggest leaving out any URL path you wish to be accessible, such as "/** " or "/resources/** " and protect just the other path(s) of your api, which in your case should be the one defined in your controller "/api/v1/students/** ". You can do that in a similar way as the snippet below:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    // http
    //     .securityMatchers( (matchers) -> matchers
    //     .requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/"))
    //     .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
    //     .anyRequest().permitAll());

        
    http 
        .securityMatchers( (matchers) -> matchers
        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/students/**"))
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic();
    
    return http.build();
}
```